# Do I store blog posts in a database? And how do I continue to make posts?

Tags: database, web-development

I'm trying to make a simple blog from scratch, but it occurs to me that I probably shouldn't have a bunch of static html pages that I link to, especially since I want the home page to be a cascade of previews of each post. So I was thinking I would store the posts in a database, and I would just retrieve parts for the home page and then the whole thing for each individual post's page. But as a beginner, I have two problems.

The first is that I don't know if that's good practice or what anyone actually does. Every time I see examples or tutorials of how to use databases, it always has very short data like name and address and number of kids. Never an entire blog post. And also not the pictures that would go along inside the post. So is there another way to store all that information? Do you maybe store file names in the database? I'm particularly concerned about images, I have no clue how that works.

The second issue is once it's all set up and online, I don't know how I would continue to update it. Would I make a POST route that only I can access? That sounds like a security risk to me.

Forgive my ignorance, I guess it's just such a simple question that I can't find anything that answers it explicitly. I don't know the right nouns to ask well enough, so I'm just looking for some best practices.

Comment: What's your reason for wanting to create your own blogging solution, rather than using an existing solution?

Comment: @DavidArno Just to learn more. I know about WordPress and things like that, but I'm pretty interested in the inner workings.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You seem to be creating a Content Management System (CMS). Many such systems already exist, and the majority stores the content within a database.

The fact that the content may be rather large is not an issue. The database can handle large amounts of plain text or binary data per entry without problem. The important point to remember is that it doesn't make sense to enforce a maximum size for blog posts, so in an SQL database we can't declare the column with type `VARCHAR(10000)` or something like that. Instead, you probably want an unrestricted-size `TEXT` or `BLOB` type. For `TEXT` types, you'll have to pick a suitable text encoding – many databases are not quite Unicode-compatible.

Some CMSes handle static resources like images separately from page content. E.g. Wordpress lets user upload images and other files into the `/wp-content/` folder. Requests for these resources can be handled directly by the HTTP server. That is quicker than routing the request through the CMS.

A CMS always has a management interface where you can log in, configure the system, and create and edit content. This should require a login (e.g. OpenAuth or password over HTTPS). The CMS backend checks each request that would affect settings or content for proper authorization: the user must be logged in and must have the necessary rights, if the CMS includes a rights management system. That can be done securely, but it is easy to make fatal mistakes especially if you haven't created a web application before. The most common problems are SQL injection vulnerabilities or bugs in the authorization check for each protected action. If the site allows content to be generated by untrusted users (comments, a search bar, or a 404 page that displays the missing URL), then XSS attacks are also possible.

In recent years, static blogging has become increasingly popular. Here, no CMS runs in the web server. Since there is no code, there can be no security problems in our code. Instead, all HTML files were created on a different computer and then uploaded to the web server. The tool that creates the HTML files from the content can be arbitrarily complex. I've written my own static blogging engine imitating Jekyll, and it supports a tag system, post excerpts on the home page, RSS feeds, theming, …. The only features that a static system cannot have are dynamic features like user comments or a search bar, at least not without using 3rd-party providers.